# [Vue warn]: Missing required prop

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I am using `Nuxt` and trying to create `Heading` component. when try to use this component, it renders `h1` tag properly but the problem i am facing is in the console. It shows **[Vue warn]: Missing required prop: "level"**. i don't know why. I'm new to `Vue` and `Nuxt`.

> My Heading.vue file

```
<template>
  <component :is="type" :level="level" class="heading">
    <slot />
  </component>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: {
    level: {
      type: Number,
      required: true
    }
  },
  computed: {
    type() {
      if (this.level === 1) {
        return "h1";
      } else if (this.level === 2) {
        return "h2";
      } else if (this.level === 3) {
        return "h3";
      } else if (this.level === 4) {
        return "h4";
      } else if (this.level === 5) {
        return "h5";
      } else {
        return "h6";
      }
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

> My Page.vue file where i am using this component

```
<script>
import Btn from '~/components/Button/Button.vue'
import Heading from '~/components/Heading.vue'
export default {
    components: {
      Btn,
      Heading
    },
    data: () => ({
    columns: [
      {
        image: "banner-1.jpg",
        columnHeading: 'Column 1',
        columnDesc: 'Lorem ipsum '
      },
      {
        image: "banner-2.jpg",
        columnHeading: 'Column 2',
        columnDesc: 'Lorem ipsum '
      },
      {
        image: "banner-3.jpg",
        columnHeading: 'Column 3',
        columnDesc: 'Lorem ipsum dolor'
      }
    ]
  })
}



</script>

<template>
    <b-container>
      <Heading :level="1">test</Heading>
        <b-row class="py-5">
            <b-col cols="12" md="4" v-for="(items, index) in columns" :key="index">
                <img :src="`images/${items.image}`" alt=""/>
                <h5 class="my-3">{{ items.columnHeading }}</h5>
                <p>{{ items.columnDesc }}</p>
            </b-col>
        </b-row>
        <Btn to="/about">I'm a Button</Btn>
    </b-container>
</template>

<!-- Add "scoped" attribute to limit CSS to this component only -->
<style scoped lang="scss">

</style>
```

[image: The error shows in the terminal]

> My Hero.vue file

```
<template>
<div class="position-relative">
  <parallax :speed-factor="0.3">
    <img src="~/assets/images/man.jpg" alt="Zed-FED" />
  </parallax>
  <div class="hero-text text-center">
    <Heading :level="3">Hey, I'm Zuber</Heading>
    <Heading :level="2">Web Dev</Heading>
    <Heading>I am a senior Web Developer of Classy Theme. 
I love to code, travel, music &amp; foods.</Heading>
  </div>
</div>
</template>

<script>
  import Parallax from 'vue-parallaxy'
  import Heading from '~/components/Heading.vue'
  export default {
    components: {
      Parallax,
      Heading
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Remove the colon in your page template: `<Heading level="1">test</Heading>`

Comment: @Aer0 no its not working for me :( it still showing an error **[Vue warn]: Missing required prop: "level" found in <Heading> at components/Heading.vue**

Comment: The colon is use to avoid using ` " ` when you want to pass variables to a component. So Try  `<Heading :level=1>test</Heading>` because you need an integer.

Comment: It seems you don't need `:level="level"` in the `<component :is="type" :level="level" class="heading">`

Comment: @bcjohn sorry but i am not getting what you are trying to say. so where do i need that? and how will that works without that?

Comment: Is there more to the error message? There should be a bit where it says *found in...* that might help us to figure out what's going wrong. The colon before `:level` is correct as it has type `Number`.

Comment: @Zuber would you mind trying to use `:level="'1'"`? If that won't work I'm going to build up a minimal example to test that. Or maybe you've some fiddle/codepen to share already?

Comment: @skirtle i have added screenshot

Comment: @Aer0 i have added screenshot

Comment: Could you post the code for `Hero.vue`? The problem appears to be there.

Comment: @skirtle ya sure

Comment: @skirtle check my edit, i have added code for `Hero` file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is this bit of `Hero.vue`:

```html
 <Heading>I am a senior Web Developer of Classy Theme. 
I love to code, travel, music &amp; foods.</Heading>
```

You aren't passing the `level`.

Unrelated but in `Heading.vue` you should be able to change this:

```html
<component :is="type" :level="level" class="heading">
```

to:

```html
<component :is="type" class="heading">
```

The `level` isn't required there unless you want to add a `level` attribute to your `<h1>`. You should be able to see the effect in the developer tools if you inspect the resulting element. There'll be a `level="1"` in the DOM that you probably don't need.